# Dropping text up to a special character with Parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm new to Haskell and Parsec --- my apologies if this question is trivial.

I want to parse lines of text that are structured like this:

```
<Text to be dropped> <special character (say "#")> <field 1> <comma> <field 2>
<comma> <field 3> <special character 2 (say "%")> <Text to be dropped>
```

I want my parser to discard the "text to be dropped" at the beginning and at the end, and to
keep the contents of the fields. My main problem is understanding how to write a parser that drops everything up to a certain special character.

The parsers from the library that seem helpful are anyChar, manyTill and oneOf, but I don't understand how to combine them. I would be grateful for any simple example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When writing Parsec code, it is useful to first write out the grammar that you want to parse in [BNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebnf) form first, because parsers written in Parsec end up very much looking like the grammar.

Let's try that:

```
line ::= garbage '#' field ',' field ',' field '%' garbage
```

In the above production, we assume a production named `garbage`, whose actual definition will depend on what text you actually want dropped. Likewise, we assume a production named `field`. Now let's write this production out as parsec code:

```
line = do
  garbage
  char '#'
  field1 <- field
  char ','
  field2 <- field
  char ','
  field3 <- field
  char '%'
  garbage
  return (field1, field2, field3)
```

This code reads exactly like the BNF. The essential difference is that the results of some of the subproductions are named, so that we can return a value built from these results (in this case a tuple).

Now i don't know what your notion of garbage is, but for the sake of example let's assume that you mean any whitespace. Then you could define `garbage` as follows:

```
garbage = many space
```

(or, alternatively, it so happens that parsec already has a combinator for parsing zero or more spaces called `spaces`). If the garbage could be anything except the `#` delimiter character, then you could say

```
garbage = many (noneOf "#")
```

This line will munch all input up to and excluding the first '#'. Either way, whatever value `garbage` produces as a result, since you are not binding a name to the value it will be thrown away.

Comment: I think noneOf only parses one character, so you need to combine it with something like many.  There is also skipMany which I think is more efficient when you are just throwing away the result.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use applicative parsers:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String

type Field = ()                 --your type here

field = string "()" *> pure ()  --your parser here

parser :: Parser (Field, Field, Field)
parser = manyTill anyChar (char '#') *>
         ((,,) <$> (field <* char ',')
               <*> (field <* char ',')
               <*> (field <* char '%'))
```